# Shortcut to open a new line at any position of the current line in R studio script

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R studio for hunderd of times a day. I write many lines. I would like to jump to a new line under a current line (at any position) without going to the front or the end of line and then hit enter. Is there any shortcut to do so? any help please?

Comment: Why not just "End > Enter"? Or "End > *arrow down*" (if you don't want to create a new line). How long does it take you to execute that?

Comment: @DavidArenburg that is what I usually do ~

Comment: Rstudio supports `vim` mode of key bindings (tools -> global options -> code -> editing). In command mode, you can just press 'o' to start a new line below.

Comment: @mt1022 Well, in order for this to work, you need to CTRL + S each time, so I'm not sure how much time it saves. Still not about the laziness going on around this question.

Comment: @DavidArenburg，why the ctrl+S do? I usually use vim in terminal, but not in rstudio. It seems changing from editing mode to command mode requires Esc in rstudio too. I didn't get your point.

Comment: @mt1022 I mean that it's not just `o`. So Either you do `o + ESC` or `o + CTRL + S` or just `End + Enter` or `End + arrow down` with the normal mode. I don't see any benefit of one over another. Neither I see the point of this question. This pretty much like asking "*I'm too lazy to push the RStudio icon when opening RSTudio, is there any shortcut to open RStudio without pressing the icon*"?

Comment: It is not the lazy! I write many lines and sometimes I need to go to edit specific argurment or word and then need to go to the end of the line or the front and hit enter. So, I just want most faster way to do so.

Comment: I don't get the hate for wanting to be efficient - `End` is out of the way on many keyboards and substantially slower than something like `Shift + Enter` in PyCharm. The best thing I've found is `Alt + Right` to replace `End`, then `Enter`

Answer (score 0):

There is an official feature request for this [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/3075)

Because it's a feature request, you can use a hotkey/text expander program to map Shift + Enter -> Command + Right , Enter